# Multiple video call (n users) using Peerjs in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webrtc, peerjs

I have an application in which I am trying to get video chatting to work in React Native.

Used packages like react-native-webrtc and react-native-peerjs.

Created peer js server using Node Js.

One to One Video call is working fine with react native Peerjs. But, Now I want more than 2 users to be connected upto n users.

Is it possible to convert one to one video call to Multiple video call. Kindly let me know how Multiple video call can be achieved using Peer js and web rtc.

Here is my code for one to one video call:

Initialize webrtc and PeerJS:

```
const initialize = async () => {
const isFrontCamera = true;
const devices = await mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();

const facing = isFrontCamera ? 'front' : 'environment';
const videoSourceId = devices.find(
  (device: any) => device.kind === 'videoinput' && device.facing === facing,
);
const facingMode = isFrontCamera ? 'user' : 'environment';
const constraints: MediaStreamConstraints = {
  audio: true,
  video: {
    mandatory: {
      minWidth: 1280,
      minHeight: 720,
      minFrameRate: 30,
    },
    facingMode,
    optional: videoSourceId ? [{ sourceId: videoSourceId }] : [],
  },
};

const newStream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);

setLocalStream(newStream as MediaStream);

console.log("************ Started ************");
// const io = socketio(SERVER_URL);
// io.connect();

console.log(SERVER_URL);
const io = socketio.connect(SERVER_URL, {
  reconnection: true,
  autoConnect: true,
  reconnectionDelay: 500,
  jsonp: false,
  reconnectionAttempts: Infinity,
  // transports: ['websocket']
});

io.on('connect', () => {
  console.log("----------- Socket Connected -----------");
  setSocket(io);
  io.emit('register', username);
});

io.on('users-change', (users: User[]) => {
  console.log("----------- New User - " + JSON.stringify(users) + " -----------");
  setUsers(users);
});

io.on('accepted-call', (user: User) => {
  setRemoteUser(user);
});

io.on('rejected-call', (user: User) => {
  setRemoteUser(null);
  setActiveCall(null);
  Alert.alert('Your call request rejected by ' + user?.username);
  navigate('Users');
});

io.on('not-available', (username: string) => {
  setRemoteUser(null);
  setActiveCall(null);
  Alert.alert(username + ' is not available right now');
  navigate('Users');
});

const peerServer = new Peer(undefined, {
  host: PEER_SERVER_HOST,
  path: PEER_SERVER_PATH,
  secure: false,
  port: PEER_SERVER_PORT,
  config: {
    iceServers: [
      {
        urls: [
          'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302',
          'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
});

peerServer.on('error', (err: Error) =>
  console.log('Peer server error', err),
);

peerServer.on('open', (peerId: string) => {
  setPeerServer(peerServer);
  setPeerId(peerId);
  io.emit('set-peer-id', peerId);
});

io.on('call', (user: User) => {
  peerServer.on('call', (call: any) => {
    //Alert.alert("PeerServer Call");
    setRemoteUser(user);
    Alert.alert(
      'New Call',
      'You have a new call from ' + user?.username,
      [
        {
          text: 'Reject',
          onPress: () => {
            io.emit('reject-call', user?.username);
            setRemoteUser(null);
            setActiveCall(null);
          },
          style: 'cancel',
        },
        {
          text: 'Accept',
          onPress: () => {
            io.emit('accept-call', user?.username);
            call.answer(newStream);
            setActiveCall(call);
            navigate('Call');
          },
        },
      ],
      { cancelable: false },
    );

    call.on('stream', (stream: MediaStream) => {
      setRemoteStream(stream);
    });

    call.on('close', () => {
      closeCall();
    });

    call.on('error', () => { });
  });
});
```

};

When a user call another user:

```
const call = (user: User) => {
if (!peerServer || !socket) {
  Alert.alert('Peer server or socket connection not found');
  return;
}

if (!user.peerId) {
  Alert.alert('User not connected to peer server');
  return;
}

socket.emit('call', user.username);

setRemoteUser(user);

try {
  const call = peerServer.call(user.peerId, localStream);

  call.on(
    'stream',
    (stream: MediaStream) => {
      setActiveCall(call);
      setRemoteStream(stream);
    },
    (err: Error) => {
      console.error('Failed to get call stream', err);
    },
  );
} catch (error) {
  console.log('Calling error', error);
}
```

};

Now, how should I call multiple user from the code below and how multiple streams have to be handled.

```
const call = peerServer.call(user.peerId, localStream);
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to convert one to one video call to Multiple video call

It's not possible to "convert" a one to one video call to "multiple" in a peer-to-peer architecture. In a p2p architecture with `n` participants, each participant will have a separate, one-to-one connection with the rest `n-1` other participants.

I may possibly be misunderstanding your question, but if you're asking whether it's possible to establish `n-1` connections for each participant, then the answer is yes. Here's how I would implement:

1. Anytime a new participant joins a session, extract their peer information. This is the `peerId` provided by the peer.js library.
2. Next, let the rest of the participants know about the presence of this new user. For this, you'll share this new participant's name, `peerID` and any other metadata with the rest of the participants in the room. This can be done by the signalling logic that you have implemented using socket.io.

Now going forward, you have 2 options:

1. The new participant could initiate the one-to-one peer connection with others in the room, OR,
2. The rest of the participants could initiate a one-on-one connection with the new participant.

Personally I prefer the first. So continuing the process:

1. Using the same signaling logic via socket.io, the rest of the participants will let the new user know about their presence by providing their own peer information and other metadata.
2. Once the new participant gets everyone's peer information, initiate a new peer connection using `call.on('stream', callback)` and start broadcasting their video.
3. On the recipient side, when a call is received along with the stream, you'll create a new video element in react-native, and bind the received media stream to this element. Which means, each participant will have `n-1` video elements for streaming the media of `n-1` other participants. The recipient also starts to broadcast their own video to the initiator of the call.

[Here's a tutorial](https://egen.solutions/articles/how-to-build-your-own-social-audio-chat-application-part-2) showing how this can be done using vanilla JavaScript, along with the [github repository with source code](https://github.com/booleanhunter-tech-blog/clubhive).

---

Now, to answer the next question:

> Kindly let me know how Multiple video call can be achieved using Peer js and webrtc.

This depends on the number of participants, where they lie geographically, browser/device limits, device computational power, and network bandwidth. So there are multiple factors involved which makes it tricky to give any specific number.

Browsers can place their own upper limits on the maximum number of connections possible, and there might be other values for Android and iOS. On chrome, the max theoretical limit is [500](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/third_party/+/1b6aa2b5c4d9ef48255799dc6f4b4d16426c0207/blink/renderer/modules/peerconnection/rtc_peer_connection.cc#148). If you're developing for Android, you may want to check [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/HEAD/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/PeerConnection.java). But I couldn't manage to find much info on this.

Most practical applications involving WebRTC don't rely on a mesh architecture. Common implementations involve using an SFU, which takes multiple media streams and forwards them. A slightly more sophisticated technique is an MCU architecture, which combines all those media streams from multiple participants into a single one, and send that single stream to the rest of the participants.

I discuss this in some detail here:

https://egen.solutions/articles/how-to-build-your-own-social-audio-chat-application-part-2/#architectures-scaling-and-costs

Here's a nice [article](https://blog.eyeson.com/mcu-sfu-mode) that explains the difference between SFU and MCU.

Comment: SFUs do *not* combine streams, they forward. This is what differentiates them. You might want to update your article.

Comment: @PhilippHancke Ah, thank you for pointing out the error! I will update the article